# Good blogs/articles/ books on building highly scalable systems?

Tags: performance, scalability

Any good blogs/articles/ books on designing highly scalable systems? Good source code for studying would help a lot too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best blog I know of: http://highscalability.com/

Comment: +1 for highscalability.com. It's probably the only blog that is staying current with the technology trends and is mostly unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

Some good articles & case studies [here](http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the [OTP material of Erlang](http://erlang.org/).

Answer (score -1):

This blog is focused on fundamentals of performance and scalability: http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/